# Adding EKParticipants to an EKEvent in EventKit

Tags: iphone, eventkit

I'd like to programatically add a participant to an EKEvent on the iPhone.

EKParticipant's class reference states "You do not create EKParticipant objects directly. Send attendees to an EKEvent object to get an array of EKParticipant objects.".

EKEvent's class reference states that the 'attendees' member (NSArray) is "The attendees associated with the event, as an array of EKParticipant objects. (read-only)"

Seems like a chicken-and-egg scenario - how does one "Send attendees to an EKEvent object", if the attendees member a.) is read-only and b.) contains objects that cannot be directly created?

Comment: I guess you send the message `-attendees` to get the already existing attendees. Doesn't look like there's a way to add attendees yourself yet. If you let the user create events then you could use the view controllers in EventKitUI to provide that functionality. Otherwise, wait for iOS x where x > 5 :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add attendees to an EKEvent, you must implement EKEventKitUI, and use the view controllers of that framework, this framework provide the calendar native like views so you can add attendees for your EKEvent.

But you can't add attendees to EKEvent programmatically since the attendees is a read- only property, so you ca't set it's value by code, and since you ca't create EKParticipant object directly by code.

may be this limitation change in coming versions of iOS.

Comment: Have you confirmed that EventKitUI provided a way to add attendees?