# Invite attendees for event like Sunrise

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icloud, icalendar

I've reviewed the [Sunrise](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sunrise-calendar-for-google/id599114150?mt=8) app with adds participant and sends mails to them. I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627694/modifying-ekparticipants-attendees-in-eventkit-like-sunrise) question. But it gives error like this.

```
Save failed with error: Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=31 "Attendees cannot be changed" UserInfo=0x7f85a06d5880 {NSLocalizedDescription=Attendees cannot be changed}
```

Could any one solved this error?

Comment: @matt It's similar like iCal

Comment: Check out my answer here, it's solving a very similar (same?) issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30787801/1145804

Comment: @rebello95 I'm getting the above error when i was trying your answer.

Comment: @matt Sorry for the delayed reply. I meant you are asking what kind of calendar app. That's why I replied as iCal. It normal all calDav calendars where we can create event with attendees.

Comment: @matt Why you have marked my question as duplicate? Can you check my question and also your answer? I'm asking that you answer is not working for me? Can't understand that.

Comment: It is exactly the same question.

Comment: @matt Yes. But given solution is not working for me.

Comment: But asking the same question again won't change that.

Comment: @matt Do you have the solution for the error?