# Adding attendees to an Exchange calendar event in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, exchangewebservices, eventkit

### Summary

As part of my current project, our team is tasked with creating an event in an Exchange calendar and inviting a given email address.

We have so far discovered three ways to do this, each with their own problems.

---

### Unsuitable Solutions

- **Event Kit**

Calendar events can be added easily enough, and although we found [a *workaround* to add attendees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30787801/916299), this is explicitly **unsupported**.

> Event Kit cannot add participants to an event nor change participant information.
>   <sub>[[Source]](https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekparticipant)</sub>

- **Exchange API**

We considered communicating directly with the Exchange API, but **this was discounted** because it would require the user to authenticate twice, once with our own Web API, and once with Exchange.

- **Web API**

The last option we had, was to send a request through our own Web API (which is already authenticated with Exchange) so that it could make the request on behalf of the app. This was vetoed, among other reasons, because of security concerns.

---

### Question

Are there any options that we have missed for adding an event to an Exchange calendar and adding an attendee, please?

What are the limitations of those options?

Comment: Maybe you could create the event and somehow manually send out the invitation via iMIP? I don't know how Exchange reacts to a reply it doesn't expect (as it doesn't have a participant record), but it may be worth a try. Besides that I guess you should provide more information on "This was vetoed, among other reasons, because of security concerns". If you already have the authentication, why wouldn't you use it? (that your server has the auth is a security issue, but I can't see how using it is one)

Comment: We, the dev team, asked the same questions, but it was the CTO who had made the final decision. I believe time constraints and reducing web requests are some of the other reasons not to use the web api. That option also seemed the most logical to us.