# Is there a way to modify my attendance status using iOS EventKit?

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I retrieve events from my calendar  using Apple's [EventKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit)

Now I have a list of my events with details. **I'd like to choose a particular event and change my (and only my) attendance status** (i.e from Maybe to Accept).

I can't see an obvious option for that. I can read:

- *"EventKit cannot add participants to an event nor change participant information."*  [EkParticipant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekparticipant)
- *"Attendees is read-only property"* [Attendees](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekcalendaritem/1507140-attendees)

Is there a way to do that?

I noticed the other approach with using [EkEventEditViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkitui/ekeventeditviewcontroller).
I'd like to avoid that if possible.

PS.
I saw these, but I thought they're kinda outdated:

- [How to accept/decline EKEvent invitation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170415/how-to-accept-decline-ekevent-invitation)
- [EKEvent accept event invtation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962832/ekevent-accept-event-invtation)
- [Adding EKParticipants to an EKEvent in EventKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669643/adding-ekparticipants-to-an-ekevent-in-eventkit?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used [EventKitUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkitui) and it works.